# Mysql: Join two tables by values from a map passed as a procedure parameter

Tags: mysql, database

So I have two MYSQL tables:

**Table 1**:

| id | name | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 4 |
| 2 | B | 5 |

**Table 2**:

| id | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cell 1 |
| 2 | cell 2 |
| 3 | cell 3 |

And I need to join them (key <-> id) but not **directly**. I have a map for which key which id coresponds. For exampe **[{4,1}, {5,3}]**. The map shoud be passed as a parameter to the procedure. Then after the join the table should look like this

| Table 1 id | name | Table 2 id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | cell 1 |
| 2 | B | 3 | cell 3 |

I thought of creating an temporary table and use it for joins. But I can't find the right syntax for this operation (since I am passing the array as a string). Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way of handling this would be to maintain a *junction* table which contains the relationships between the two tables, something like this:

```
-- table_1_to_2
id1 | id2
1   | 1
2   | 3
```

Then, do a basic join:

```sql
SELECT t12.id1, t1.name, t12.id2, t2.header2 AS name
FROM table_1_to_2 t12
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.id = t12.id1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t12.id2;
```

If you are calling your stored procedure from an application, then you should ensure that the junction table exists at the time of the call.

Comment: yes, but I want to pass the mapping as a parameter to the procedure (and maybe create a temp table), not to maintain a global table

Comment: You should include your proc code.  Most likely, there are already questions which show how to pass a table valued parameter to a MySQL stored proc.